# ssl certificate on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

hi all i host on my ubuntu server a couple of web sites
unfortunatelly i reboot my server and the certificates stopped working

my websites are www.prometheas.it and www.offertegaseluce.it

lets take for examples prometheas:

my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/energia/?$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin/?$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /?p=$1&var=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /?p=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?prometheas\.it$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.prometheas.it/$1
```

as you can see i would like not to apply rules to the directories energia and phpmyadmin and i would like to send all traffic to https://www.

after rebooting i rennovate all certificates with https://www.sslforfree.com

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin info@prometheas.it
ServerName prometheas.it
ServerAlias *.prometheas.it
DocumentRoot /var/www/prometheas
ErrorLog /var/www/prometheas-ssl-error_log
CustomLog /var/www/prometheas-access_log common
<Directory /var/www/prometheas/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/prometheas/certificate/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/prometheas/certificate/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/prometheas/certificate/ca_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

ports are opened

```
root@blueserver:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

root@blueserver:~# sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

```
sshd        486     root    3r  IPv4    6978      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd        486     root    4u  IPv6    6980      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
vsftpd      521     root    3u  IPv4    7087      0t0  TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
glance-re   534   glance    4u  IPv4    8332      0t0  TCP *:9191 (LISTEN)
glance-ap   535   glance    4u  IPv4    8330      0t0  TCP *:9292 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   15u  IPv4    7422      0t0  TCP *:4190 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   16u  IPv6    7423      0t0  TCP *:4190 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   20u  IPv4    7430      0t0  TCP *:110 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   21u  IPv6    7431      0t0  TCP *:110 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   22u  IPv4    7432      0t0  TCP *:995 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   23u  IPv6    7433      0t0  TCP *:995 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   27u  IPv4    7440      0t0  TCP *:143 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   28u  IPv6    7441      0t0  TCP *:143 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   29u  IPv4    7442      0t0  TCP *:993 (LISTEN)
dovecot     680     root   30u  IPv6    7443      0t0  TCP *:993 (LISTEN)
nrpe        812   nagios    4u  IPv4    7384      0t0  TCP *:5666 (LISTEN)
opendkim    882 opendkim    7u  IPv4    7591      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8891 (LISTEN)
apache2     916     root    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2     916     root    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
master     1012     root   12u  IPv4    7923      0t0  TCP *:25 (LISTEN)
master     1012     root   13u  IPv6    7924      0t0  TCP *:25 (LISTEN)
master     1012     root   17u  IPv4    7929      0t0  TCP *:465 (LISTEN)
master     1012     root   18u  IPv6    7930      0t0  TCP *:465 (LISTEN)
apache2    3073 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    3073 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    3074 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    3074 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    4445 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4445 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    6760 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    6760 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    6865 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    6865 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    6874 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    6874 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    7327 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    7327 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    7625 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    7625 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    7730 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    7730 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    9270 www-data    3u  IPv4 2038403      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    9270 www-data    4u  IPv4 2038405      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
vsftpd    10285   nobody    5u  IPv4 2078108      0t0  TCP 10.12.8.5:50380 (LISTEN)
mysqld    29101    mysql   10u  IPv4  151184      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
```

muduls are enabled

```
a2enmod ssl
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
Module setenvif already enabled
Considering dependency mime for ssl:
Module mime already enabled
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
Module socache_shmcb already enabled
Module ssl already enabled
```

Comment: The ufw rules do not make sense when comparing these with the actual server. `www.prometheas.it` is currently at 178.239.178.51 and can be reachable by http (port 80) and refuses the connection on https (port 443). Your ufw rules show that port 443 is open but port 80 not which contradicts what is visible from outside. My guess is that you are not looking at the system which gets actually accessed from the internet.

Comment: thanks but i must underline that login as: root
root@178.239.178.51's password:

Comment: i updated the question